# How to get exact value from fixture in @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, testing, pytest, parametrized-testing, pytest-fixtures

I use **pytest fixture** which return object **{"article_new_1": article_new_1, "article_new_2": article_new_2}**:

```
@pytest.fixture
def create_articles_new(create_categories):
    article_new_1 = ArticleFactory.create(category=create_categories["category_1"], status=ArticleStatusChoices.NEW)
    article_new_2 = ArticleFactory.create(category=create_categories["category_2"], status=ArticleStatusChoices.NEW)
    return {"article_new_1": article_new_1, "article_new_2": article_new_2}
```

I try to parametrize a test using the fixture. I would like to paste two articles of the fixture to **@pytest.mark.parametrize**.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "article,expected",
        [
            ('create_articles_new.article_new_1', 200),
            ('create_articles_new.article_new_2', 403),
        ],
)
def test_articles(client, article, expected):
    res = client.get(reverse("get_article", kwargs={"article_guid": article.guid}))
    assert res.status_code == expected
```

**QUISTION**: What should I paste instead of **create_articles_new.article_new_1** and **create_articles_new.article_new_2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a fixture create the parametrization, it needs to be called by declaring `indirect=True`. However, you wouldn't have `expected` as a separate test function argument. Instead, `article` would be a `tuple` consisting of the `Article` object (I assume that `ArticleFactory` creates `Article`) and the expected result:

```py
import pytest
from _pytest.fixtures import SubRequest


@pytest.fixture()
def article(create_categories, request: SubRequest) -> tuple[Article, int]:
    return (
        ArticleFactory.create(
            category=create_categories[request.param[0]],
            status=ArticleStatusChoices.NEW
        ),
        request.param[1],
    )


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "article",
    [
        ("category_1", 200),
        ("category_2", 403),
    ],
    indirect=True,
)
def test_articles(client, article: tuple[Article, int]) -> None:
    res = client.get(
        reverse("get_article", kwargs={"article_guid": article[0].guid})
    )
    assert res.status_code == article[1]
```

**Notes**:

- Fixtures can access passed parametrization arguments via `request` fixture and its `param` property.
- `article` fixture doesn't need to return a tuple. You could have it return a dict, data class, or whatever you find more suitable.
- `SubRequest` is imported only to give you a hint what object your fixture would be working with. You can omit it.

Comment: Thank you very much for a prompt answer! Sorry for question from a testing newbie, but I don't understand how to get **category_1** and **category_2**. I run the test and received **ValueError: Cannot assign "'category_1'": "Article.category" must be a "Category" instance.**

Comment: @Sergey I guess that's because I omitted the use of the `create_categories` fixture. Have a look at the code now.

Comment: yes, it's more clear now) thank you! But I have another problem: fixture **create_categories** returns **{"category_1": category_1, "category_2": category_2}**. I changed it similar to your recommendations according to **create_articles_new**. But **create_articles_new** uses another fixture (**product**) which does not use any fixtures. When I run test I get an error: **AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'**. What could be the problem?

Comment: The `param` property is AFAIK available in the `request` fixture only if the main fixture was used in parametrization. It wouldn't be available when it's used in other fixtures such as `create_categories`.